# Erro de transações do mysql no php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transações

Bom dia galera do forum.
Eu estou tentando fazer o insert simultâneo, ai estou usando controle de transação no php, só que ele não faz o primeiro insert, então, ele me gera um erro de foreign key.

```
public function insert(){
    try{

        self::getInstance()->beginTransaction();
        self::getInstance()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //insert manufactures
        $insertPJ = "INSERT into trein_pj VALUES ( NULL,:cnpj,:razao_social,:nome_fantasia,:tel_comercial1,:tel_comercial2)";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($insertPJ);
        $stmt->bindParam(":cnpj",$this->cnpj,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":razao_social",$this->razao_social,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":nome_fantasia",$this->nomeFantasia,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tel_comercial1",$this->tel_comercial1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tel_comercial2",$this->tel_comercial2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        //insert peoples
        $insertPF = "INSERT INTO trein_pf VALUES (NULL,:nome,:cargo,:rg,:cpf,:tel_fixo,:tel_celular,:email,:escolaridade,:formacao,:tempo_experciencia,:aceite,:data_registro,:ip_registro,:id_trein_pj,:id_treinamento)";

        $stmt = DB::prepare($insertPF);
        $stmt->bindParam(":nome",$this->nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":cargo",$this->cargo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":rg",$this->rg,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":cpf",$this->cpf,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tel_fixo",$this->tel_fixo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tel_celular",$this->tel_celular,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email",$this->email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":escolaridade",$this->escolaridade,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":formacao",$this->formacao,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tempo_experciencia",$this->tempo_experiencia,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":aceite",$this->aceite,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":data_registro",$this->data_registro,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ip_registro",$this->ip_registro,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_trein_pj",$this->id_trein_pj,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_treinamento",$this->id_treinamento, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        if (self::getInstance()->commit()) {
            return true;
        }

    }catch (PDOException $ex){
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        self::getInstance()->rollBack();
    }
}
```

Agradeço, desde já os membros do forum.

Answer (score 1):

O erro de FK não necessariamente indica que o primeiro insert não ocorreu, mas sim que a FK não foi encontrada.

Após executar o primeiro insert você precisa armazenar a ID gerada nesse insert para poder fazer o bind no segundo insert.

```
//insert manufactures
$stmt->execute();
//atribui a ID inserida ao atributo id_trein_pj do objeto
$this->id_trein_pj = DB::lastInsertId();
```